# Jquery autocomplete conflicts with iOs spelling tools

Tags: jquery, ios

I've got a small problem with the jquery autocomplete tool. When I start typing, the jquery is proposing me some autocomplete options, but iOs spelling tools also, If the visitor is clicking on the autocomplete option, the spelling proposition, is also added to the final value of the input text. here below an example of what I mean.
[image]

Does someone knows how to prevent Ios spelling tool to act when jquery autocomplete is activate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize jQuery autocomplete you have to add `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the inputs you do not want to have native autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

For example:

```
var $someInput = $('.some-input');
$someInput.autocomplete();
$someInput.prop('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Comment: Of course, I alreayd did it, it's working for Desktop browser, but not for iOS